# Determine if the phone supports cover art image files and the right filename and format

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, media-player, album-art

My music library master is stored in my PC, and I sync to my phone on a regular basis. Most of my album covers are stored in separate image files inside the related album folder, whereas very few of them are embedded in songs metadata.

Now, I noticed the stock ROM player in my phone is not able to handle the covers in separate image files; only covers embedded in metadata are shown.
So I googled around and I understand now there is no guarantee a certain player can handle separate albumart pictures and there is no fixed filename and format.

So I'd like to know if there is a way to determine if a player can handle separate albumart pictures and the filename and format it uses (e.g. `AlbumArt.jpg`).

Comment: The only ways for this, apart from analyzing all source code: 1) reading the app descriptions 2) visiting its home page and checking for more details 3) asking in the dedicated forums 4) asking the dev. Oh, and 5) googling around :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Google Play Music app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music) (which is the stock music player in many phones, and is available for phones running Android 2.2 up if not) to play your music then this Google Support article "[Copy music files directly from your computer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1250234)" says:

> If your music files have accompanying artwork in .jpeg format, rename
>   the art file albumart.jpg and include it in the same folder as your
>   music files.